# Documentation on HERE api responses

Tags: rest, here-api

I am using the Routing API v8 to get instructions on how to get from one point to the other. I want to provide the user with a time and distance estimate.

Still trying to figure out how to get the distance, but for the time, I have been adding the "duration" fields but the result is very different from what I experience in that route. Additionally, there are also other fields in the response that I am not very sure about their meaning. For example, in the below response:

```
...
    "actions": [
        {
            "action": "depart",
            "duration": 133,
            "instruction": "Head northwest on Flint Close. Go for 124 m.",
            "offset": 0
        },
        {
            "action": "turn",
            "duration": 168,
            "instruction": "Turn right onto Vicarage Lane. Go for 158 m.",
            "offset": 3,
            "direction": "right",
            "severity": "quite"
        },
        {
            "action": "turn",
            "duration": 234,
            "instruction": "Turn left onto Deanery Road. Go for 233 m.",
            "offset": 9,
            "direction": "left",
            "severity": "quite"
        },
...
```

What does the `offset` property mean? Is there somewhere where I can find more information on these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the properties, you can find them in the OpenAPI specifition document [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.3.1/swagger/v8.yaml)

E.g., for "offset", it is a property for a few actions (like TurnAction in the spec),
offset:
description: Offset of a coordinate in the section's polyline.
type: integer

Regarding to distance, it should be in the summary section.

For a route which duration is not expected, we will need a deeper analysis. Please provide the exact API call you used in the comment, and we can run a check on that.

Also, please feel free to try our refclient [here](https://refclient.ext.here.com/) for a quick feeling of our Routing APIs and varies parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for sending the link for the documentation. However, I could not find a direct way to getting to it from the [dev guide landing page](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.3.1/dev_guide/index.html). It would be much more helpful if it was directly linked somewhere there.

As per the `summary`, I also notice that there is no easy to find way to get a list of the available options to be passed in the request. 

The sandbox you sent is very helpful and should also be more prominent on the resources made available for developers.